# Module has no exported member 'CanActivate' in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-fullstack

I am working on a full stack development using Angular, Node.js and MySQL. I am trying to add a route guards in my **auth-guard.service.ts** file but, when I try to import CanActivate from @angular/core, it gives an error.

```
 Module '"../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'CanActivate'.
```

Here is my code:

> admin-layout.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserComponent } from '../../pages/user/user.component';
import { TableComponent } from '../../pages/table/table.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../pages/icons/icons.component';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'user',           component: UserComponent },
{ path: 'table',          component: TableComponent },
{ path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent }
];
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/core';  //gives an error here
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: There are no module of Angular that need to be imported from `../../..`. You always want to have `@angular/moduleName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place.

[image]